# How do I break this while loop? (putting break just gives the error of break not properly in loop)

Tags: python-2.x

I need to be able to have my program break the loop and end when the user says no. Break does not work as it will just give the error of "Break not properly in loop.)

```
import random

import time

 motiv_list = ["aaaaaaaaaaa", "frick"]

 while True:

    UserFeeling_str=raw_input("How are you feeling today?")

    if UserFeeling_str == "happy":

        print(random.choice(motiv_list))

        time.sleep(1.50)

        QuoteReplay_str=raw_input("Would you like to hear another quote?")

if QuoteReplay_str == "yes":

     print()

elif QuoteReplay_str == "no":

    # (need to know what goes here)
```

Comment: just use `break` ?

Comment: yeah thats the problem. it doesnt work.

Comment: You need to indent your code correctly. When you do, the break will work as you expect.

Comment: print does not need brackets in python 2.x

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an indentation issue.

```
import random

import time

    motiv_list = ["aaaaaaaaaaa", "frick"]

    while True:

    UserFeeling_str=raw_input("How are you feeling today?")

    if UserFeeling_str == "happy":

        print(random.choice(motiv_list))

        time.sleep(1.50)

        QuoteReplay_str=raw_input("Would you like to hear another quote?")

        if QuoteReplay_str == "yes":

                print()

        elif QuoteReplay_str == "no":

            break
```

But there are a few caveats here with unspecified behavors:

- what if `if UserFeeling_str != "happy":`
- what if `QuoteReplay_str` is neither `yes` or `no`?

  - you could have a `if QuoteReplay_str == "yes"` and then an `else` instead of an `elif QuoteReplay_str == "no"`

Comment: thanks for the help. and this project is early so i havent added stuff like such as that.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation in the example is outside of the while loop.

```
import random

import time

motiv_list = ["aaaaaaaaaaa", "frick"]

while True:

    UserFeeling_str=raw_input("How are you feeling today?")

    if UserFeeling_str == "happy":

        print(random.choice(motiv_list))

        time.sleep(1.50)

        QuoteReplay_str=raw_input("Would you like to hear another quote?")

    if QuoteReplay_str.lower() == "yes":

        print()

    elif QuoteReplay_str.lower() == "no":

        break
```

Should work. Adding .lower() also allows you to accept "NO" and "YEs" as valid replies.

Alternatively, you can include it in the while loop condition as it's at the end of the loop activities:

```
QuoteReplay_str = ""

while QuoteReplay_str.lower() != "no":
    #rest of stuff
```